# how to use gradiant for fill gap between elements

Tags: css, responsive-design

I have below design :
[image]

to do this , I use below code :

```css
html,body{
    height:100% !important
          ;padding:0 !important;margin:0 !important}
body{
    overflow-y:hidden;
    overflow-x:hidden;
}

#main{
    width:100%;
    float:right;
    text-align:right;
    height:100%;
    
}
#main>div
{
    display:inline-block;
    margin-bottom:-0px;
    float:right;
}

#triangleWrapper {
    width: 18%;
    height:100%;
   

}

.segmentTriangle {
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
left: 0px;
top: 0px;
background: transparent linear-gradient(to left top, #e94d4d 50%, transparent 50%) repeat scroll 0% 0%;
}
.segmentTriangleleft
{
    width: 100%;
height: 100%;
left: 0px;
top: 0px;
background: transparent linear-gradient(to right bottom, #f65c5b 50%, transparent 50%) repeat scroll 0% 0%;
}
.col-zozan
{
        width:20%;
    height: 100%;
    display:inline-block;
     min-height:100%;
    background: blue;
margin:0 auto;
    -webkit-transition: all 300ms ease-in;
    transform: skew(-25deg);
}
#red{
    background: red;
}
#lime{
    background:lime;
}
```

```html
        <div id="main">
            <div style="float: right;" id="triangleWrapper">
                <div style="height: 100%;" class="segmentTriangle"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-zozan" id="blue"></div>
            <div class="col-zozan" id="red"></div>
            <div class="col-zozan" id="lime"></div>
            <div style="float: left;" id="triangleWrapper">
                <div style="height: 100%;" class="segmentTriangleleft"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

but I have two problems , I have two blank space in left and right , how can I put color with Triangles color ,
[image]
how can I solve it ?
I try use back ground color , but Triangle Left and Triangle Right don't have the same color , and I don't use  background color in body .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's a nice question, I've made some changes in your html, and create this idea. My idea was set the corners with: 50% of screen. And the col-zozan has 20%. I think the html will be pretty good and semantic. And it's good because can be responsible. See the code below if you can understand.

```css
html,body{
    height:100%;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
}

body{
    overflow:hidden;
}

#main{
    width:100%;
 height:100%;
 position: relative;
 padding-left:20%;
}

.col-zozan {
    width:20%;
    height: 100%;
 float: left;
    transform: skew(-25deg);
 z-index: 500;
 position:relative;
}

.corner{
 transform: none;
 position: absolute;
 width: 50%;
}

.left{
 left:0;
 background: #e94d4d;
}

.right{
 right:0;
 background: #f65c5b;
 z-index: 100;
}
.blue{
 background: blue;
}
.red{
    background: red;
}
.lime{
    background:lime;
}
```

```html
<div id="main">
 <div class="col-zozan corner left"></div>
 <div class="col-zozan blue"></div>
 <div class="col-zozan red"></div>
 <div class="col-zozan lime"></div>
 <div class="col-zozan corner right"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered using a linear gradient?

```css
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
}

body {
    background-color: #60ae71;
    background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, -7.3% 13.7%, 107.3% 86.3%,color-stop(0, #17497e),color-stop(0.2, #17497e),color-stop(0.2, #20c2be),color-stop(0.4, #20c2be),color-stop(0.4, #fabb00),color-stop(0.6, #fabb00),color-stop(0.6, #91dc3a),color-stop(0.8, #91dc3a),color-stop(0.8, #20c2be),color-stop(1, #20c2be));
    /* Android 2.3 */
    background-image: -webkit-repeating-linear-gradient(330deg,#17497e 0%,#17497e 20%,#20c2be 20%,#20c2be 40%,#fabb00 40%,#fabb00 60%,#91dc3a 60%,#91dc3a 80%,#20c2be 80%,#20c2be 100%);
    /* IE10+ */
    background-image: repeating-linear-gradient(120deg,#17497e 0%,#17497e 20%,#20c2be 20%,#20c2be 40%,#fabb00 40%,#fabb00 60%,#91dc3a 60%,#91dc3a 80%,#20c2be 80%,#20c2be 100%);
    background-image: -ms-repeating-linear-gradient(330deg,#17497e 0%,#17497e 20%,#20c2be 20%,#20c2be 40%,#fabb00 40%,#fabb00 60%,#91dc3a 60%,#91dc3a 80%,#20c2be 80%,#20c2be 100%);
}
```

[Here is a fantastic tool for creating complex gradients](http://www.virtuosoft.eu/tools/css-gradient-generator/?t=linear&d=angle&r=on&a=120&sp=17497e_0_%25__17497e_20_%25__20c2be_20_%25__20c2be_40_%25__fabb00_40_%25__fabb00_60_%25__91dc3a_60_%25__91dc3a_80_%25__20c2be_80_%25__20c2be_100_%25)